# WinError 10038 in a child class of socket in Python 3

Tags: python, class, sockets

I made the follow class:

```
class Client(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Client, self).__init__()

        self.settimeout(None)

        self.radd = None
        self.port = None
        self.buffersize = None

    def connect_to_server(self):
        self.connect((self.radd, self.port))

    def configure(self, radd:str, port=49305, buffersize=2048):
        # close the socket
        self.close()

        # assign a new configuration
        self.radd = radd
        self.port = port
        self.buffersize = buffersize
```

and i used it as follow:

```
c = Client()
c.configure('192.168.1.1')
c.connect_to_server()
```

but i get the error: [WinError 10038]

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 10038 is [WSAENOTSOCK](https://win32errors.com/0x00002736).

> An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.

It is happening because you are closing the socket before you connect. If you call `close()`, you have to create a new socket after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was really trivial, I still need to be able to reuse the Client object, can I use shutdown()?

Comment: Just hold an internal `socket` object instead of inheriting from it.